# No networks found after computer sleeps overnight with open browsers

Tags: internet-connection

I recently updated my computer to windows 8.1. It was working fine except for the annoying updates.  Just recently I started noticing that it cannot find any network after computer is left on a sleep mode over night. I am thinking the last update cause this problem. How can I fix it? Help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check whether "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is enabled on the "Power Management" tab.

The Power Management tab can be seen at Start > Computer > right click > Device Manager > select the Network Adapter > Properties option.

If it is enabled, please disable it and check whether it works for you.